# Why can’t HashSet just use bit array internally instead of HashMap to save some space?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I see that HashSet in Java internally use HashMap to check whether a HashSet contains a element or not. Can’t it just use a bitmap for storing all the hash results from strings. Eg. String abc hashed to say, 12 index and we can just set this index to show that it is present. It would save lot of space as compared to HashMap as we don’t have to store actual keys in the data.

Comment: `abc` might hash to `12`. But so will a near infinity of other strings. The maximum length for a string is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - there are quite a lot more permutations of an array that size than the range or hashcode. So - with your bitset suggestion - how do you deal with collisions?

Comment: Note that `EnumSet` does use a "bit array": such an approach works well for enums because they are densely packed (no gaps), and, for the most part, pretty small (most enums have fewer than 64 elements, and so can be packed into a single long; but to store sets of bigger enums, you just need extra longs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a HashSet were used for a contains() lookup only, an optimization like that might be possible. It would still be dangerous, because hash collisions can always occur. I think what you are looking for is a [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (note that a Bloom Filter doesn't give exact answers, it just rules out false negatives).

A Hash Set is a collection, and a collection needs to have a possibility to retrieve the values stored. Hashes are not reversible, you can't calculate the original string from its hash.